# Issue with Databind() Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

Trying to bind data to a list box. I am using DataBind several times throught my project with no problems, here I don't understand what the problem is.
When I use DataBind() I'm getting this error.

```
An exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'Motherboards'.
```

ASP:

```
<asp:ListBox ID="lbCategories" runat="server"></asp:ListBox>
```

C#:

```
protected void getCategories()
{
    DAL dal = new DAL(conn);
    dal.AddParam("all", "0");
    DataSet ds = dal.ExecuteProcedure("spGetCats");

    lbCategories.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    lbCategories.DataTextField = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["catName"].ToString();
    lbCategories.DataValueField = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["catID"].ToString();
    lbCategories.DataBind();
}
```

Database Table:

```
CREATE TABLE tbCats (
    catID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    catName VARCHAR(32)
)
```

Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spGetCats(
    @all CHAR NULL
)
AS BEGIN
    IF @all IS NULL
        SELECT * FROM tbCats
    ELSE
        SELECT * FROM tbCats WHERE catID <> 1
END
GO
```

Inserts:

```
INSERT INTO tbCats (catName) VALUES ('All'), ('Motherboards'), ('Memory'), ('Hard Drive'), ('SSDs'), ('CPUs'),
                                    ('Video Cards'), ('Computer Cases'), ('Monitors'), ('Keyboards'), ('Mice')
```

Answer (score 0):

The `DataTextField` and `DataValueField` need to be the column names.  You code was setting them to the values in the first row.

```
protected void getCategories()
{
    DAL dal = new DAL(conn);
    dal.AddParam("all", "0");
    DataSet ds = dal.ExecuteProcedure("spGetCats");

    lbCategories.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    lbCategories.DataTextField = "catName";
    lbCategories.DataValueField = "catID";
    lbCategories.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Just as I realized what the problem was you posted. lol thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the following lines:

```
lbCategories.DataTextField = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["catName"].ToString();
lbCategories.DataValueField = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["catID"].ToString();
```

to:

```
lbCategories.DataTextField = "catName";
lbCategories.DataValueField = "catID";
```

or this might also work:

```
lbCategories.DataTextField = ds.Tables[0].Columns["catName"].ColumName;
lbCategories.DataValueField = ds.Tables[0].Columns["catID"].ColumnName;
```

it needs name of the column to look for in the source which would be binded as display text and value, your current code is saying to look for the value in first row which is coming **Motherboards** and there is no column in your data source with name like that.